# How to create a custom Air map view and draw a polygon using map box in android application

Tags: java, android, polygon, marker, mapbox-android

I am using the map box SDK in which I have to set different map types.
Mostly I have to use an air map view using map box SDK.
I want to implement a view like the below image.

[image]

How would I achieve a view and also how to draw a polygon like this image?

Answer (score 0):

Follow https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/ to set up the Maps SDK and add a basic map to your Android app.

https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/examples/draw-a-polygon/ shows how to draw polygons on the map. This is if you have the coordinates only on the device.

You could use [the Mapbox dataset editor](https://docs.mapbox.com/studio-manual/reference/datasets/) + https://studio.mapbox.com/datasets, to draw the polygons instead. Then export the dataset to a vector tileset and then reference the tileset in a Maps SDK `VectorSource` https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-android-demo/search?q=VectorSource

No matter how you add the data to the map, you'll want to do the additions in a separate method if you'll be switching map styles on the fly. After the style is successfully changed and loaded, re-add the data/layers.

You could use multiple GeoJSON `Polygon` objects or [a single GeoJSON `MultiPolygon`](https://dev.socrata.com/docs/datatypes/multipolygon.html)

Comment: Hello @langsmith, Thanks for the answer.
It's gonna really help me to draw a polygon on the map but I am still struggling with the map style which you can see on the above image.
I want to achieve the same as the above image (airspace view).

Comment: What does "struggling with the map style" mean? Happy to help, but I'm still not sure what are you struggling with regarding the image you posted? The map camera being a top-down view on the map? You want the map to have the same colors? What does "airspace view" mean to you?